# Python-3.6 : Compare 2 Large unsorted delimited files based on given column match

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement to compare 2 large unsorted delimited files in Python.

As I am new to python I request to need the best way to do this.

Requirement as below.

1. There will be two large files abc.txt and xyz,txt.
2. Most of the time (99.9%) no of columns of both file will be same.
3. In both files for sure there will be one column named PSN.
4. If PSN of both files matches then i need to check rest of the
       columns of it in both the files matches

Comment: Have you tried anything that didn't work out?

Comment: Does this pertains to an accademic assignment? That being the case you should check the rules of your school about external help, or ask yout TA, before you use an eventual answer and find yourself in a quagmire.  That said, I second @Djib2011 comment: irrespective of assignment, self study, hobby or work, you should show us what you have done and tell what went wrong, or the ideas that you couldn't grasp, or the details that were elusive.

Comment: @Djib2011 - I need just to know the best way to write it. I  tried comparing using readlines() and set it was faster than with pandas dataframe. I need to compare column by column. with one of the key column as said earlier.So, Kindly request to let me know what is the best way to do this. Thanks in advance.